# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<String, DayConsumptionDto[]>' has no index signature

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm stucked with this issue and I didn't find any solution even if there is a lot of question around this error, in my case I have a Map and I coudn't apply the solutions.

Here is my code :

I have to convert a map to send to the back-end like this :

```
const convMap = {} as Map<String, Array<DayConsumptionDto>>;
    map.forEach((val: Array<DayConsumptionDto>, key: string) => {
      convMap[key] = val;
    });
```

I'm getting this Error :

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<String, DayConsumptionDto[]>' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'convMap.set'?
```

if I put `const convMap = {} as any` it works perfectly but I don't do that, can you please help me to fix it ?

Comment: same as convMap, I have just to convert it to and array of key values to be sent to the back, so let map = new Map<string, DayConsumptionDto[]>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this

```
const convMap:{[key:string]:Array<DayConsumptionDto>}[] = []
    map.forEach((val: Array<DayConsumptionDto>, key: string) => {
      convMap[key] = val;
    });
```

this will create an array

or

```
const convMap= {} as {[key:string]:Array<DayConsumptionDto>};
    map.forEach((val: Array<DayConsumptionDto>, key: string) => {
      convMap[key] = val;
    });
```

this will create an object

Comment: Thanks a lot dude ! Worked perfectly with the second one because I'm using an Object.